# How can I have my website check the visitor's java installation and offer to update or install it?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I made a website (well, a pair of websites: [MiningForJapan.org](http://www.miningforjapan.org/) and [MiningForJoplin.org](http://www.miningforjoplin.org/)) that allow visitors to contribute to a Bitcoin Mining Pool to benefit Red Cross relief efforts.

Anyway, the bitcoin mining code relies on the user's browser having an up-to-date and enabled Java runtime plugin, and the site doesn't look any different when it's not working.

How can I check that Java is running, and pop in a warning message with a link to download Java if the check fails?  The site is mainly written in PHP, if that matters (I don't see why it would).

Comment: So you want the users to donate cpu-time.  If the website is identical if it works and if it doesn't, perhaps you are TOO sneaky?

Answer (score 3):

Sigh, well, whatever the deal is with donating CPU power, you can use http://java.com/js/deployJava.js, then

```
if (!deployJava.versionCheck("1.0")) {
  // Let pre-v1.0 users know what they're missing
}
```

The correct solution is to offer them a link to [Java](http://www.java.com/inc/BrowserRedirect1.jsp)'s download page, of course.